# How to adjust PivotTable Filters

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I'm trying to create a macro that will pull some data from a pivot table into a collection variable. What I'm wanting to do is to collect each Article's Sales Forecast and Insight each month for a single year (image below). The issue I have is that I don't know how to collect the information without it being shown in the pivot table, and I don't know how to have the macro adjust the column filters to meet my requirements.

[image]

I don't have access to the source of this pivot table and I'm reluctant to have the user manually adjust the table's column filters.

For clarification, the column filter goes by Year -> Quarter -> Month -> Week.

**Edit:**

What I'm trying to accomplish starts with a schedule workbook where the relevant article numbers are kept. The Master Scheduler has a different workbook with the input values (pivot table above) to base the calculations. This input workbook only has pivot tables and I don't know where it pulls the data; just this is where the Master Scheduler manually finds the relevant data.

My thought process is to pull the relevant articles from the scheduling workbook, pull all of the articles for one full year, sort out only the relevant articles, and place the sorted information into a new location in the Schedule workbook.

The issue I'm coming across is that the column filters may not be showing all of the relevant data and I don't know how to make VBA set the pivot table's filter to prevent this. The solutions that I have found changes the F9 cell, "Year," to an actual year value, which is not what I want to do.

In addition, when you manually open the column filter to select which year, there are four quarters (or seasons) where all four must have a check mark in the box for all twelve of the months to be available.

Hopefully this clarifies my question.

Comment: I've read through this question a couple times and I'm not sure what you're trying to do... so you want to create a `New Collection` (why??) and then load it with these Article numbers with their Insight quantities (what are these? I see two columns for insights and then your picture is cut off, are there more??). You need to be more specific and/or use layman's terms as to what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Also, you don't have access to the source data? Is the worksheet containing the source data protected?

Comment: Yes, it is a controlled document. I'm importing the data from the controlled workbook into another workbook where I can use the data without the restrictions.  Once the data is collected, I can sort through for the relevant information.  There are over a several hundred Articles to sort through.

Comment: @dwirony Does this clarify the questions?

Comment: I'm sorry but no - we still can't tell what you're expecting output should be - I'm guessing that's why your question hasn't gained any traction. You need to clarify what you're trying to get from this.

Comment: What are you hoping to accomplish with a collection? Have you used collections before? Out of curiosity, why not an Array or a Dictionary?  Also, you must have access to the source data if you can create/edit a pivot table based on it. Perhaps you can't *change* the data but that's irrelevant as long as the data is laid out in an organized logical fashion. (And even if it werent, a copy and paste-link gives you your own "copy" of the data.)...  It's unclear what you're trying to accomplish. What data do you have, and what does it need to look like when it's done.

Comment: I've used collections before; I have not used Pivot Tables before. The number of rows changes frequently, so an Array will not work. I've dabbled with Dictionaries, and this may be a case where a Dictionary should be used over a collection.

Comment: This excel workbook only has pivot tables and is created by someone outside of where the building. The person I'm designing this for has access and can change the filter setting in the pivot table, but the copy I have does not allow me to change the filters, probably because it cannot connect to the source. Under standard conditions I wouldn't even look at the pivot table but the source to pull data. However, this is the only place to collect the information.

Comment: The short answer to what I'm looking to accomplish is to have the pivot table show the current year only, and the twelve months. Then I can proceed in collecting the data, sorting out that which is only relevant articles, and then place that information into a different table. 

The longer answer I have is, can this be done more effectively than through my approach?

Comment: *The longer question I have is,....

Comment: @ashleedawg Does this help or am I failing to properly communicate my issue?

Comment: @dwirony Does this help or am I failing to properly communicate my issue?

Comment: It sounds like you just need to group your existing pivot table differently.  I'm writing this from my phone, so "as I recall" you just need to click your pivot table anywhere in the date field, then on the ribbon there will be 2 tabs specific to pivot tables. Click Design (?) And then "remove grouping" and then "group" and un-select every date-part except for the Year. (I might have the steps wrong but google "group pivot table by year" for the exact steps.) This is all assuming your dates are stored as valid Excel dates (not text).

Comment: I think I see my mistake when I asked my question now. I'll update it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research, I found this website that answers my question: [Expand and Collapse Entire Pivot Table Fields – VBA Macro](https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/expand-collapse-entire-pivot-table-fields-buttons/). I've also learned about the `pt.ClearAllFilters` command.

If the website becomes unavailable in the future, the code is also listed below.

**Expand:**

```
Sub Expand_Entire_RowField()
    'Expand the lowest position field in the Rows area
    'that is currently expanded (showing details)

    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim pf As PivotField
    Dim pi As PivotItem
    Dim iFieldCount As Long
    Dim iPosition As Long

      'Create reference to 1st pivot table on sheet
      'Can be changed to reference a specific sheet or pivot table.
      Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)

      'Count fields in Rows area minus 1 (last field can't be expanded)
      iFieldCount = pt.RowFields.Count - 1

      'Loop by position of field
      For iPosition = 1 To iFieldCount
        'Loop fields in Rows area
        For Each pf In pt.RowFields
          'If position matches first loop variable then
          If pf.Position = iPosition Then
            'Loop each pivot item
            For Each pi In pf.PivotItems
              'If pivot item is collapsed then
              If pi.ShowDetail = False Then
                'Expand entire field
                pf.ShowDetail = True
                'Exit the macro
                Exit Sub
              End If
            Next pi
          End If
        Next pf
      'If the Exit Sub line is not hit then the
      'loop will continue to the next field position
      Next iPosition

    End Sub
```

**Collapse:**

```
Sub Collapse_Entire_RowField()
'Collapse the lowest position field in the Rows area
'that is currently expanded (showing details)

Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pf As PivotField
Dim pi As PivotItem
Dim iFieldCount As Long
Dim iPosition As Long

  'Create reference to 1st pivot table on sheet
  'Can be changed to reference a specific sheet or pivot table.
  Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)

  'Count fields in Rows area minus 1 (last field can't be expanded)
  iFieldCount = pt.RowFields.Count - 1

  'Loop backwards by position of field (step -1)
  For iPosition = iFieldCount To 1 Step -1
    'Loop fields in Rows area
    For Each pf In pt.RowFields
      'If position matches first loop variable then
      If pf.Position = iPosition Then
        'Loop each pivot item
        For Each pi In pf.PivotItems
          'If pivot item is expanded then
          If pi.ShowDetail = True Then
            'Collapse entire field
            pf.ShowDetail = False
            'Exit the macro
            Exit Sub
          End If
        Next pi
      End If
    Next pf
  'If the Exit Sub line is not hit then the
  'loop will continue to the next field position
  Next iPosition

End Sub
```

**Edit: Solution Specific**

```
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pf As PivotField

Set pt = ws.PivotTables(1) 

'Setting all of the column filters to desired setup
For Each pf In pt.ColumnFields
    pf.Hidden = False
    pf.ClearAllFilters

    'Drill Down until Months are opened, then exit the loop
    If UBound(Split(pf.Name, "Month")) > 0 Then
        pf.DrilledDown = False  '<-- Ensuring nothing beneath "Months" is 
        Exit For
    Else
        pf.DrilledDown = True
    End If
Next
```